# How can I change ImageButton size from xml in java

Tags: java, android, xml, resize, android-imagebutton

I have a some problem in my android project.

This is my xml code for ImageButton with fixed width and height.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/ball1"
    android:background="@drawable/ball"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And here i called in java that **ImageButton**:

```
ImageButton ball1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ball1);
```

My question is, what I need to do, to **subtract** my ***layout_width*** and ***layout_height***
by 10dp in java code?

Something like this:

```
int width = ball1.getWidth();
    int height = ball1.getHeight();
width = width - 10dp;
height = height - 10dp;
```

So how can I subtract Height and Width by 10dp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by

```
imagebutton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

or use following link

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/resize-button-programmatically-using.html